# Execute PHP script in background... what is the best solutions for my case?

Tags: php, background-process

I am working on a emailer system that I have to plug in a CMS for a company. I am looking for a way to make the email sender script run in background while the admin may navigate or even close the browsers.

I found the PHP function named `ignore_user_abort()` which is required to keep the page running even if it has timed-out.

Now I have three solutions to "start the script" :

1. I could use an iframe
2. I could use an Ajax call which I have previously configured to timeout very early. Eg: using the [jQuery framework](http://jquery.com/) : `$.ajaxSetup({ timeout: 1000 });`
3. I could use a cron job but I would like to avoid this solution since they are "virtual" and are unstable on that server.

Is there any other solutions? I dont really like the iframe solution but I already use them with an Ajax uploader script.

I dont want the admin to hit **F5** and start a second instance of it.

The company's users have been told to only log in the CMS using Firefox.
Thank you

Comment: does the user have to press a button (or something) to start the send process ?

Comment: Yep he does. After editing the email content and importing his contact list. He must press a button.

Comment: You could just use your own suggestion but add something in the database that says its running or tag a tmp file or even session variable to prevent it from running twice if they hit f5.

Comment: What exactly does 'virtual' mean in the context of cron jobs? If you cannot reliably run cron jobs then that is probably something that needs to be addressed.

Comment: I dont understand either. But they told me a while ago that it's the only way they could make scheduled runs. I tried at that time to avoid the deep informations because I am no network administrator. I am waiting for a reply from them right now. If I get more explaination on why they aren't using a regular cron system I will post it here. But as for now, I know their system isn't very good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can run a PHP script in the background using `Exec()`.

[php docs](http://si.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#86329) provide an example on how you can do that:

```
function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } 
    else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
}
```

Comment: Will the page freeze while the PHP script executed in the `exec()` is running?

Comment: @Cybrix no, that's the point. A command run trough this function will run in the background, so user is free to leave the page and he will not have to wait for the command to finnish.

Comment: Then, that seems to be an option. I have already contacted the technical support to see if I (or more specifically the script) allowed to use the exec() command. I will keep you updated.

Comment: It's been confirmed that I can use that solution. Thank you.

Comment: could you explain the rest of this more?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would write a background daemon to do this.  I would save all my emails to a database in the original HTTP call and have a script constantly running in the background that checks every, say, 30 seconds to see if there are any pending emails and then sends them.

This would also allow you to check for duplicates when you add emails to the queue, so you needn't worry about multiple additions.

---

**Edit** Given your reason for not using cron jobs (i.e. you don't have shell access to the server) I wouldn't use this approach.

Instead I would have a first AJAX call where the PHP inserted all the emails into a database, and returned a key to the Javascript. I would then have a Javascript call, using that key, where PHP processed emails for 5 seconds, then returned the number of emails remaining to the browser. I would then have Javascript keep repeating this request until there were no emails remaining.

This would have the additional benefit that you could have progress notifications and, if the server crashed for whatever reason, your emails would be recoverable.

Comment: @Cybrix No, it would be a shell command. Since it seems that you can't use shell commands, I'd use the approach I've just detailed in my edit.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but the user must be able to leave the page or close the browser.

Comment: @Cybrix Fair enough. In that case, I'd use Jan's approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you close the browser the script started by php should not stop executing. So as I see it you have a couple of ways to do this:

1. Send a POST to the server telling it you want to do some action, and the script executes until it finishes. Reloading the page will warn the browser about that you will need to resend data etc... You could do the POST asynchronously with javascript to prevent this and to be able to do other things while the script is executing. One thing to watch out for here is that the script execution time might be limited.
2. Send a POST to a script that in turn starts a background system process doing the same thing. But now you will not be able to find out the progress unless you save the state somewhere, in a database or something
3. Cron (you already seem to have explored this option)